# Can modifying a property cause a method to be called?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, affinetransform

Can someone explain me why in iOS

```
 var dx = (touchPoint.x - dragTouch.x) * self.transform.a
 var dy = (touchPoint.y - dragTouch.y) * self.transform.d

 self.transform.tx = self.transform.tx + dx 
 self.transform.ty = self.transform.ty + dy

 if ( self.frame.origin.y > 70){ // lock upper edge during drag
       self.frame.origin.y = 70
 }
```

is different from

```
 var dx = (touchPoint.x - dragTouch.x) * self.transform.a
 var dy = (touchPoint.y - dragTouch.y) * self.transform.d

 if ( self.frame.origin.y > 70){ // lock upper edge during drag
       self.frame.origin.y = 70
 }

 self.transform.tx = self.transform.tx + dx 
 self.transform.ty = self.transform.ty + dy
```

It seems that modifying a property causes a method to be called, and consequently a redraw of the view.
If i use the first solution, the edge of my view is locked, otherwise, using the second piece of code, i obtain a different behaviour.

Do you know how i can avoid this problem?

Comment: In the first code, the transform is done first and then the `y` is set while in the second code the `y` position is set first, and then the transformation is done.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but my question is slightly different. These should be, in my mind, only static variables assignments, that don't affect frame.origin.
I'm not calling methods, and i would like to redraw only when i want to.

Comment: Modifying a property named `myProperty` causes the `setMyProperty:` method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

As @HotLicks kind of adressed there is probably stuff going on in the background. Since we don't know the implementation details it is hard to say with certainty.

- Option #1 would be what @HotLicks said:
  In that scenario there's a `private` property, which you are only able to access via a `get` and/or `set` within a different, `public` computed property.
- Option #2 would be almost the same:
  It is possible that the property has `willSet` and/or `didSet` property observers. This would be a different approach to the same principle as in option #1.

You probably can't avoid this. But you probably should not try to either. There's usually a reason why the implementation is as it is. And having a seperate `get`/`set` or property observers is a method of constraining your (the programmer's) actions in a way to suit to the given framework.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i guess i solved the problem.
The documentation says that every time a frame property is modified, methods like setNeedsUpdateConstraints() are called, and that causes a layout redraw. I solved avoiding to modify directly frame properties, modifying only dx and dy.